# Create taskbar badge notification for multi-instance uwp app

Tags: uwp, notifications, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I am using [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/badges) to add taskbar badge to a multi-instance editor app to notify user of unsaved changes. The problem is this works only for the first instance. Is there any way I can have notification badges for all my instances (different taskbar badge icon for all my instances)??

[Edit]

The editor app is a multi-instance app with tabs. I want each instance to reflect number of unsaved files/tabs with their taskbar icon badge count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you could use [`LocalSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer?view=winrt-19041) to record unsave save count, and that data could be shared with different app instance.

```
private static void UpdateSharedInstanceNumber()
{
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    object data = localSettings.Values["UnSave"];
    if (data == null)
    {
        localSettings.Values["UnSave"] = 0;
    }
    if (AppInstance.GetInstances().Count == 0)
    {
        // Write data to settings, using this app instance's ID.
        // If there are no other instances, we reset the InstanceCount.
        localSettings.Values["UnSave"] = 1;
        UnSaveNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Read the settings data, and increment it.
        UnSaveNumber = (int)localSettings.Values["UnSave"] + 1;
        localSettings.Values["UnSave"] = UnSaveNumber;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I'm afraid it could not be realized currently, all the instances will share one badge, so we suggest you record all unsave count and display all.

Comment: May be I wasn't clear about the question, I want all the instances to have their respective badge count in the taskbar. I have modified my question with more details.

Comment: I'm afraid it could not be realized currently, all the instances will share  one badge, so we suggest you could record all unsave   count and display all.